# How to resolve { "error" : "invalid_grant", "error_description" : "Bad Request" } issue in google contact api

Tags: java, google-api

public class GoogleContact {
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();

```
static String clientId="";
static String clientSecret="";
static String token="";

public static void main(String[] arg)  {
    ContactsService  service = new ContactsService("contacts.googleapis.com");

    NetHttpTransport    httpTransport=null;
    try {
            httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException | IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
    .setTransport(httpTransport)
    .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
    .setClientSecrets(clientId, clientSecret)
                .build().setRefreshToken(token);
    try {
        credential.refreshToken();
        service.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);
        service.useSsl();

    } catch (Exception   e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

}
```

}
response is :
com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "error" : "invalid_grant",
  "error_description" : "Bad Request"
}
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:105)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:287)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.executeRefreshToken(Credential.java:570)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:247)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same exception. Then I generated a new credentials.json file and deleted the old token from tokens folder. Then I run the program, it worked and a new token was generated.

Comment: Hi, where is the tokens folder? I new to delete the old token. Thanks.